# How can I convert this data structure to an array?

Tags: javascript

I had this data

```
var list = {
        "data": [
            {
                "value": "58",
                "color": "red"
            },
            {
                "value": "45",
                "color": "blue"
            },
            {
                "value": "63",
                "color": "green"
            },
            {
                "value": "32",
                "color": "yellow"
            },
            {
                "value": "25",
                "color": "orange"
            }
        ]
    }
```

I want only values for `array` and `color` in one array.

Comment: `JSON.parse()` as outlined in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/how-to-parse-json-in-javascript

Comment: show your expected output.

Comment: Do you want "value" and "color" as a 2 separate javascript array ?

Comment: A JavaScript data structure is not JSON.

Comment: I don't understand what the data structure you want to get out of this is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work cross-browser

```
var values = [];
var colors = [];

for (var i = 0; i < list.data.length; i++) {
    values.push(list.data[i].value);
    colors.push(list.data[i].color);

};
```

Comment: nice answer but beware of [cross-browser compatibility issues](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Browser_compatibility) (IE8 and below mostly)

Answer (score 0):

The code below should achieve if what i understand from your question is correct.

```
var colorArray = [];
var valueArray = [];

for(var i in list.data) {
  colorArray.push(list.data[i].color);
  valueArray.push(list.data[i].value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map()` method of `Array`:

```
var values = list.data.map(function(item) { return item.value; });
var colors = list.data.map(function(item) { return item.color; });
```

Comment: nice answer but beware of [cross-browser compatibility issues](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Browser_compatibility) (IE8 and below mostly) and it may be better to loop over the array only once

Comment: @pomeh And how you would implement such "once" loop with `map()`?

Comment: I would use `forEach` instead of `map` in this case :) But there's still cross-browser compat issues

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
 colors = [];
 values = [];
 list.data.forEach(function(val, key){ colors.push(val.color); values.push(val.value); })
```